# Qt cannot send email

Tags: qt, email, qt4

I got some source from [here](http://www.qtforum.org/article/26688/2/sending-e-mail-with-qt4.html) about how to send email using qt's socket. But the code is not sending email, rather it's stucked after connected to smtp server.

My output is like

```
1 
stateChanged  QAbstractSocket::HostLookupState 
stateChanged  QAbstractSocket::ConnectingState 
stateChanged  QAbstractSocket::ConnectedState 
Connected  
constructor
2
```

Comment: Could you please post code here, because i don't know which version of codes you used.

Comment: I used the exact version that can be downloadable from the link.

Answer (score 4):

I have written SMTP code in the past and would recommend not doing it.  There is a library called [Qxt](http://libqxt.bitbucket.org/doc/0.6/) that has classes designed to send emails (QxtSmtp, QxtMailMessage, and QxtMailAttachment).  This library is also built completely on Qt, so you get to use Qt's socket code anyways.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using some System API, calling a script on Unix or using Outlook automation on Win etc. Using SMTP directly is not as easy as it was 10 years ago (HELO/EHLO :-)). Consider authentication, firewalls, etc.
Even using webkit and a webmail provider might be easier.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I came across this SMTP Implementation in Qt which works pretty well:
https://github.com/bluetiger9/SmtpClient-for-Qt

I was pointed to it by this SO question:
[How to send mail via SMTP and get it by using Qt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717018/how-to-send-mail-via-smtp-and-get-it-by-using-qt)