# Qt - How to Send Multiple Emails Simultaneously

Tags: c++, qt, email

I'm trying to implement a feature that sends an email to multiple contacts from a Qt desktop application. At the moment I can do this

```
QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl("mailto:?to=" + emails +"&subject=" + ui->subject_edit->text() +"&body=" + text, QUrl::TolerantMode));
```

and it opens the default email application on my device. For multiple emails, however, I need to send the email from the desktop application without launching the email client from the device.

How can I achieve this, please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to send mail via SMTP and get it by using Qt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717018/how-to-send-mail-via-smtp-and-get-it-by-using-qt)

Comment: It does, thank you. This is a silly question but I'm trying to add this to my Qt project. I'm getting lots of errors that I guess have to do with the way I'm importing this project into mine. How can I include this git clone into my qt project, please? Again, it's a stupid question but I'm stumped.

Comment: You may want to look here for known issues: [https://github.com/bluetiger9/SmtpClient-for-Qt/issues](https://github.com/bluetiger9/SmtpClient-for-Qt/issues)

Comment: My second bit of advice would be spend a few hours and test the code examples independent of your code before you try to integrate into your project.